# C# WCF Web API Problems Posting/Putting

Tags: c#, http, wcf-web-api

I have a webservice that looks something like this:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/{userName}/?key={key}&machineName={machineName}", Method = "PUT")]
public HttpResponseMessage<SomeStuffPutResponse> PutSomeStuff(string userName, string key, string machineName, string theTextToPut)
{
     // do stuff
}
```

My global.asx looks like:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<SomeStuffService>("1.0/SomeStuff", new HttpHostConfiguration());
```

When I hit the webservice via C# HttpClient or fiddler it is throwing a 500 and not even getting to my method. I added a bunch of logging and am getting the following error:

> The service operation
>   'PutSomeStuff' expected a value
>   assignable to type 'String' for input
>   parameter 'requestMessage' but
>   received a value of type
>   'HttpRequestMessage`1'.

**UPDATE**: If I make theTextToPut variable a custom object it works fine. It is just giving me issues if it is a primitive type like a string.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1.

You could change the theTextToPut-parameter to a HttpRequestMessage and then read the content of the message.

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/{userName}/?key={key}&machineName={machineName}", Method = "PUT")]
public HttpResponseMessage<SomeStuffPutResponse> PutSomeStuff(string userName, string key, string machineName, HttpRequestMessage request)
{
     string theTextToPut = request.Content.ReadAsString();
}
```

Solution 2.

If you really want to get the parameter as a string you could create a operation handler that handles all string parameters named "theTextToPut".

```
public class TextToPutOperationHandler : HttpOperationHandler<HttpRequestMessage, string>
    {
        public TextToPutOperationHandler() 
            : this("theTextToPut")
        { }

        private TextToPutOperationHandler(string outputParameterName) 
            : base(outputParameterName)
        { }

        public override string OnHandle(HttpRequestMessage input)
        {
            return input.Content.ReadAsString();
        }
    }
```

Then you set up your service in Global.asax as follows:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<SomeStuffService>("1.0/SomeStuff",
                new HttpHostConfiguration().AddRequestHandlers(x => x.Add(new TextToPutOperationHandler())));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for string `theTextToPut` in the uri.

Comment: how do I specify that I want that string to be in the request body not the uri.

Answer (score 0):

As @axel22 says, probably the application is binding `theTextToPut` to the URI. As [this article states](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api), simple types are binded to the URI by default.

You could use [FromBody attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.http.frombodyattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) to force the application to bind `theTextToPut` to the request body.